# Linux - create virtual microphone and speakers

Tags: ubuntu, audio, microphone, speakers, pulse-audio

I am trying to create virtual speakers and virtual microphone on a Ubuntu docker.

I am running a process that needs to capture the PC audio (virtual speakers)
and play audio (from file) to a virtual microphone.

I am using PulseAudio as follows:

```
#Load pulseaudio virtual audio source
pulseaudio -D --disable-shm=yes --exit-idle-time=-1

# Create virtual output device (used for audio playback)
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=DummyOutput sink_properties=device.description="Virtual_Dummy_Output"

# Create virtual microphone output, used to play media into the "microphone"
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MicOutput sink_properties=device.description="Virtual_Microphone_Output"

pacmd load-module module-virtual-source source_name=VirtualMic
pacmd load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=VirtualSink

pacmd set-default-sink VirtualSink
pacmd set-default-source VirtualSink.monitor
```

**The Issue is:**

Every sound that plays to the speakers are direct to the microphone!

I need the microphone to be isolated so only if I play a file to it work and not to capture the entire system audio.

Thank you.